# Convergence of a rational sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Im trying to prove the convergence of a sequence and so far I did not have a whole lot of ideas.

Lets assume we have a convergent sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of rational numbers, so lets say $a_n = \frac{r_n}{q_n}$ with $r_n \in \mathbb{Z},q_n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\mathrm{gcd}(r_n,q_n)=1$ with $\lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty} a_n = x_0 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.
I now want to show that $\left( \frac{1}{q_n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent sequence with limit $0$.
First of all, Im not entirely sure that this statement is true, since I did not read it anywhere, but it feels like it has to be true, but I dont know why. So far I have tried to prove it using the normal definition without any success.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What if the sequence is eventually constant?

Comment: You´re right, I will edit my question, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously for some integer $m$, we have $ x_0 \in (m,m+1) $. Now observe that for every $ M > 0 $ there are only a finite number of proper fractions $r_n / q_n $ with $ q_n < M $ inside $(m,m+1)$. You can use this to show that $ q_n \to \infty $.

Comment: Thank you! Very much appreciated.